# How to access a specific value in array

Tags: arrays, typescript, vue.js, routes

I want to access each element of my "to" value of the children property in my array.

```
const items = [{
  name: 'Administrateur',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Catalogue',
      to: 'catalogue'
    },
```

and function :

```
 function openRoute() {
  items.forEach(item => {
  const route = item.children.values(?? idk)   })
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should first access to the items array and then get into children array.

```
items.forEach(item => item.children.forEach(child => child.to));
```